# Excel: Plot multiple lines with different X and Y values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a few dataset that looks like this:

| spend | return | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 20% | A |
| 60 | 30% | A |
| 70 | 40% | A |
| 15 | 15% | B |
| 20 | 25% | B |
| 30 | 40% | B |
| 45 | 20% | C |
| 50 | 30% | C |
| 55 | 50% | C |
| 50 | 50% | D |
| 55 | 55% | D |
| 60 | 60% | D |

How do I plot 4 **smoothed lines from A,B,C,D respectively in the same chart,** with each taking a different color, and a legend on the side showing which color is which.  I would like to do this in Excel.

I am so baffled as to how to do this, because I usually I would have A,B,C,D share the x values, but in this case, A,B,C,D each has their own set of Ys and Xs.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Please try to create a PivotTable first, and then create a PivotChart.

[image]